# Trying to understand JSONField for django postgresql

Tags: python, django

I'm reading [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/_modules/django/contrib/postgres/fields/jsonb/#JSONField) on JSONField, a special postgresql field type. Since I intend to create a custom field that subclasses `JSONField`, with the added features of being able to convert my `Lifts` class:

```
class Lifts(object):
    def __init__(self, series):
        for serie in series:
            if type(serie) != LiftSerie:
                raise TypeError("List passed to constructor should only contain LiftSerie objects")
        self.series = series

class AbstractSerie(object):

    def __init__(self, activity, amount):
        self.activity_name = activity.name
        self.amount = amount

    def pre_json(self):
        """A dict that can easily be turned into json."""
        pre_json = {
            self.activity_name:
                self.amount
        }
        return pre_json

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.pre_json())

class LiftSerie(AbstractSerie):

    def __init__(self, lift, setlist):
        """ lift should be an instance of LiftActivity.
            setList is a list containing reps for each set
            that has been performed.
        """
        if not (isinstance(setlist, collections.Sequence) and not isinstance(setlist, str)):
            raise TypeError("setlist has to behave as a list and can not be a string.")
        super().__init__(lift, setlist)
```

I've read [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-model-fields/#converting-values-to-python-objects) that `to_python()` and `from_db_value()` are two methods on the `Field` class that are involved in loading values from the database and deserializing them. Also, in the docstring of the `to_python()` method on the [`Field` class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/_modules/django/db/models/fields/#Field), it says that it should be overridden by subclasses. So, I looked in `JSONField`. Guess what, *it doesn't override it*. Also, `from_db_value()` *isn't even defined* on `Field` (and not on `JOSNField` either).

So what is going on here? This is making it very hard to understand how JSONField takes values and turns them into json and stores them in the database, and then the opposite when we query the database.

A summary of my questions:

1. Why isn't `to_python()` overridden in `JSONField`?
2. Why isn't `from_db_value()` overridden in `JSONField`?
3. Why isn't `from_db_value()` even defined on `Field`?
4. How does `JSONField` go about taking a python `dict` for example, converting it to a JSON string, and storing it in the database?
5. How does it do the opposite?

Sorry for many questions, but I really want to understand this and the docs are a bit lacking IMO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Django database fields, there are three relevant states/representations of the same data: form, python and database. In case of the example `HandField`, form/database representations are the same string, the python representation is the `Hand` object instance.

In case of a custom field on top of `JSONField`, the internal python might be a `LiftSerie` instance, the form representation a json string, the value sent to the database a json string and the value received from the database a json structure converted by psycopg2 from the string returned by postgres, if that makes sense.

In terms of your questions:

1. The python value is not customized, so the python data type of the field is the same as the expected input. In contrast to the `HandField` example, where the input could by a string or a `Hand` instance. In the latter case, the base `Field.to_python()` implementation, which just returns the input would be enough.
2. Psycopg2 already converts the database value to json, see 5. This is also true for other types like int/`IntegerField`.
3. `from_db_value` is not defined in the base `Field` class, but it is certainly taken into account if it exists. If you look at the [implementation of `Field.get_db_converters()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/d0f569b350bca89eeb186523d8905a6e31b5a947/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L683-L686), `from_db_value` is added to it if the `Field` has an attribute named like that.
4. The `django.contrib.postgres.JSONField` has an optional encoder argument. By default, it uses [`json.dumps` without an encoder](https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/blob/e50f3129c25aa764b3acb6205f515bab56c3f6d2/lib/_json.py#L59) to convert a json structure to JSON string.
5. psycopg2 automatically convertes from database types to python types. It's called [adaptation](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#adaptation-of-python-values-to-sql-types). [Documentation for JSON adaptation](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html?highlight=json#json-adaptation) explains how that works and can be customized.

Note that when implementing a custom field, I would suggest writing tests for it during development, especially if the mechanisms are not completely understood. You can get inspiration for such tests in for example [django-localflavor](https://github.com/django/django-localflavor).

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to answer my questions. 

on 1: So, since `to_python()` is run during `clean()` for forms, does that mean that `JSONField` expects the value gathered from the form to be a correct json string?

Comment: And again in 1: what do you mean by the value being customized?

Comment: And lastly, on 1: Is what circumstances would `to_python()` be called with `typeof(value) == Hand`and in what circumstance with `typeof(value) == str`?

Comment: The [`django.contrib.postgres.forms.JSONField` implements](https://github.com/django/django/blob/51ae4e1f324afcf1c7f6a102335dc78bfa51c126/django/contrib/postgres/forms/jsonb.py#L23) the conversation from string to JSON structure.

Comment: Customized as in: changing the functionality from the field you extend from.

Comment: Okay, so then what you're saying is that since the JSON structure in python is a string, there is no need for any type conversion by JSONField?

Comment: No, the forms.JSONField takes care of converting the string to the python dict/list/primitive structure.

Comment: Then why doesn't `JSONField.to_python()` do this conversion if that's what the method is made for? Is it because psycopg2 already has done this conversion? That seems unlikely since you said `JSONField` takes care of the converting. But then again, you said in both 2 and 5 that psycopg DOES take care of the conversion into python types...

Comment: Psycopg2 converts from db string to python structure, forms.JSONFields converts from form string to python structure. Basically the same conversion, but in different places.

Comment: So let's say a user sends in a string through a form to JSONField. Where is this conversion from string to JSON taking place? Because it doesn't seem like it takes place in the `to_python()` method, even though that's what it should do, according to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-model-fields/#converting-values-to-python-objects

Comment: Flow of input from user to database: User (json str) -> forms.JSONField (json structure) -> fields.JSONField (json structure) -> database (json str).

Comment: And what method in forms.JSONField takes care of the conversion?

Comment: to_python: https://github.com/django/django/blob/51ae4e1f324afcf1c7f6a102335dc78bfa51c126/django/contrib/postgres/forms/jsonb.py#L23

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is, both to_python and from_db_value return python strings that should serialize to JSON with no encoding errors, all things being equal.

If you're okay with strings, that's fine but I usually override Django's JSONFields's from_db_value method to return a dict or a list, not a string for use in my code. I created a custom field for that.

To me, the whole point of a Json field is to be able to interact with it's values as dicts or lists.